# Spark executing two actions at the same time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Say I have a Spark Streaming job, there are one transformation and two actions to save the data from the same parent transformation onto external storage.

```
                             -> Action1
Source -> Transformation -> |
                             -> Action2
```

My questions is, is it possible to execute **Action1** and **Action2** at the same time if I set the scheduling strategy to **FAIR**? If so, will the **Transformation** be executed for **two times** even if I cache it in memory?